# Upgrading from sudo 1.7.4p6 to 1.8.6p7 on OS X 10.7.5

Tags: macos, upgrade, software-update, sudo

I downloaded sudo for os x 10.7 from the following link, I followed the readme instructions, but when I call sudo -V I still get the old version number.  I can see the folders related claim to have been changed at the time I ran the suggested command.

Any ideas?

http://archive.hmug.org/BSD/Administration/System/sudo/1.8.6p7/

Comment: Where does it install - there seems to be no documentation

Answer (score 1):

The command `sudo tar -C / -zxf sudo-1.8.6p7-1-osx7.tar.gz` should be working, assuming you are in the same working dir as the downloaded file.

You *could* add `--overwrite` to the command, but this may have unintended effects...

I don't quite understand your desire to replace the stock `sudo` with this seeming random, and unsupported 'update'. If this goes wrong, you may be left without sudo; or you could break more than sudo.

You could uncompress without the `-C /`, and manually move the files into position.

Comment: For security purposes at work they want this version of sudo installed on all OS X platforms

Answer (score 0):

Is `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin` on the path?

If not, add `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` to `~/.bash_profile` or change the path some other way.

Comment: current PATH /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/X11/bin

I'll try moving /usr/local/bin forward

Comment: That does make the new version come up, but I need to update sudo for all users

Comment: You can also change the path in /etc/launchd.conf. If there are other programs in /usr/local/bin/, overriding the default versions might have unexpected side-effects though.